# Why do we say Eishes Chayil on Friday nights?

Tags: tefilla, meal-seudah, leil-shabbat, mishlei, aishes-chayil

Eishes Chayil is indeed a beautiful song. But why do we say it specifically Friday nights (before Kiddush)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this website it is Because  Shabbos it self is a queen
http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/205,152557/Why-do-we-recite-the-Aishet-Chayil-A-Woman-of-Valor-on-Friday-Night.html

Answer (score 9):

> The simplest answer is to show
>   gratitude to the woman of the house
>   who lead the preparations for Shabbos.
>   She is likely tired and over-worked
>   and deserves our sincere thanks!
>
> Rabbi Eliyahu Lopian zt”l (1872-1970)
>   recounted a great mystery which he set
>   out to solve. When he first came to
>   learn under the Alter of Kelm, Rabbi
>   Simcha Zissel Ziv Broida zt”l
>   (1824-98), he was in awe of the
>   Alter’s wife. Rebbetzin Chaya Leah
>   appeared to be a superwoman! She
>   cooked, cleaned, cared for her three
>   children and at the same time was
>   dedicated to every need of the Yeshiva
>   as well. How did she do so much and
>   maintain her enthusiasm and vigor?!
>
> This enigma was solved the first time
>   that young Eliyahu was invited for a
>   Shabbos meal. When they entered the
>   house after Shul on Friday night, the
>   Alter gave his wife a magnificently
>   warm greeting and enumerated to her
>   all of the appreciation he had for her
>   hard work to organize, cook and care
>   for the family’s needs. She was
>   beaming. After making Kiddish and
>   HaMotzie, the Alter smiled at the
>   Rebbetzin and told her that her
>   Challah was the sweetest and most
>   delicious that he had ever tasted. The
>   pride and joy found on the Rebbetzin’s
>   face explained everything to Rabbi
>   Lopian. When someone feels truly
>   appreciated, recognized and validated,
>   they experience a magical surge of
>   energy that inspires them to continue
>   their great accomplishments. That joy
>   and fulfillment is truly powerful.

http://www.closetotorah.com/2010/09/appreciation-and-motivation-introduction-1-the-aishes-chayil-style/

Answer (score 8):

See the [Otzer Dinim U'Minhagim quoted](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37057&pgnum=425) in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11163/603), discussing Shir HaShirim.

Quoting Minhagei Yeshurun, one of the answers is that Friday night is the time of intimacy between a man and wife.